# scp from one remote server to another remote server

Tags: debian, scp

I have one *big* file on server `one` and I want to copy it to server `two` using `scp`. I have the keys setup properly and I can ssh/scp to both servers from my desktop.

The file I need to copy is larger then the free space on my workstation's hdd, so I wanted to do:

```
scp one:/opt/bigfile.tar.gz two:/opt/bigfile.tar.gz
```

but I got:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname one: Name or service not known
```

We do not have DNS here (don't ask me why), so I have this in my ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host one
    Hostname        <IP address of server one>
    User            jspurny

Host two
    Hostname        <IP address of server two>
    User            jspurny
```

If I try with a smaller file and transfer it from `one` to my workstation and then to `two`, it works fine:

```
scp one:/opt/smallerfile.tar.gz .
scp smallerfile.tar.gz two:/opt/
```

When using IP addresses directly as suggested in comment, I got:

```
$ scp jspurny@<one's IP>:bigfile.tar.gz jspurny@<two's ip>:bigfile.tar.gz
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

**Not an issue:**

The size is not an issue here - it was only a "trigger" to this problem as there was no way to store `bigfile.tar.gz` on my workstation.
The problem occurs regardless of the file size.

**Question:**

Why does the command:

```
scp oneremote:file secondremote:file
```

throws an error regardless if using `.ssh/config` aliases or directly using ip addresses?

**Solved - sort of - still looking for explanation** - I've split the bigfile into smaller files and transfered them one by one through my workstation. I'm still wondering why it didn't work. So I would still appreciate some explanation of what was wrong ..

**Found a reason why it fails:** It seems I was being foolish. I *thought* that the command

```
scp one:file two:file
```

was creating two connections to each server and then receive data from **one** and immediately send them to **two** and thus acting like a relay.

This is clearly not the case, because a simple `-v` option revealed that it in fact just connects to **one** and from **one** it tries to connect to **two**. Which obviously isn't possible because server **one** is not supposed to connect to **two**.

Comment: Did you try just changing your scp command to use the IP addresses instead such as "scp jspurny@ip_address_server_one:/opt/bigfile.tar.gz jspurny@ip_address_server_two:/opt/bigfile.tar.gz".

Comment: @tchester: I did now, but it gives just a different error (see edited question)

Comment: related? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14187/why-does-scp-hang-on-copying-files-larger-than-1405-bytes

Comment: @slm no, I have no problems with size.

Comment: As I've found the explanation of the errors, I wanted to add/accept it as my own answer, but it seems to me a bit unfair as it actually doesn't solve the problem. Do you think I should rephrase question into: *How to copy file from server **one** to server **two** using my workstation as a relay?* or should I add my *explanation of my unability to use --verbose option* as an answer and accept it?

Comment: Your question got me thinking if this can be done with `netcat` instead of with `scp`, so I tried it and it worked just fine: on **destination** do `nc -l 12345 | tar -xv`, on **intermediate** machine do `nc -l 12345 | nc destination 12345` and on **source** do `tar -cv FILENAME | nc intermediate 12345`. Works like a charm, no data kept on intermediate machine, is faster than `scp` _but_ it's natively insecure, as the data travel the network unencrypted (unless you also pass the data from some encryption tool, like `gpg`). So, there you go, another option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Simple pipe

Try this:

```
ssh one 'cat file' | ssh two 'cat > file'
```

The first one should send the file content to your machine, while the second should send that on to second machine. I would compute a checksum at both ends after the transfer, to ensure that nothing got lost or garbled along the way.

## Elaborate tunnels

For more elaborate applications, you could use ssh tunnels. For example, you could try something like this:

```
ssh -R 5001:127.0.0.1:5002 one
ssh -L 5002:127.0.0.1:22 two
```

Then you can open a connection on `one` to machine `localhost` port `5001` and it will be forwarded twice and end up as a connection on `two` to `localhost` port `22`. This is the ssh port, so you can use this for yet another scp, or for rsync, or whatever. You could also start an `rsync` server on `two`, and forward port 873 instead of 22. Or you could use `nc` on both sides to transfer raw data, using an arbitrary port number.

The main benefit between the above approach is that you have a two-directional tcp connection between the two machines, instead of a one-directional pipe only. That way, the two parties can exchange information, which is particularly important in the `rsync` case.

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't do exactly what I *wanted*, but what I actually **needed**, which is great.

Comment: I choose this option because of its advantage that it allows to append data with >>

Answer (score 37):

Full credit for this answer goes to https://superuser.com/a/602436/142948

You need the `-3` option for scp:

```
scp -3 one:/opt/bigfile.tar.gz two:/opt/bigfile.tar.gz
```

> `-3`: Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the
>   local host.  Without this option the data is copied directly between
>   the two remote hosts.

http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=scp&sektion=1

Otherwise the 2nd alias "two" is being resolved **on host "one"**, which may not exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, this option seems to be fairly new and propagated to all distros yet.

Comment: Thanks, it works on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Comment: I don't want to use local host as intermediary. I am trying this for Akamai CDN host where I am trying to copy existing dir to new location on same host. Wondering how it can be done.

Comment: Seems this should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have user access to the source server (one) why not login and run your scp command on that server directly... If you worry that it will take too long, then start the command inside a `screen` then detach from the screen with `Ctrl+a d` and let it run.

However, if you **must** do this from your workstation, and SSH keys from source to destination server are working OK, then send the `scp` command as the parameter of an `ssh` command, like:

```
ssh user@source 'scp /path/to/file user@destination:/path/to/file'
```

Comment: Thanks, that would definitely work, except those servers both have disabled PasswordAuthentication and I can't add keys from one to another - they shouldn't be able to connect to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the error message: "Host key verification failed." would seem to be the most straightforward thing to do here. I found this Q&A on askubuntu titled: [SSH connection problem with “Host key verification failed…” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45679/ssh-connection-problem-with-host-key-verification-failed-error).

One of the [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/45685/17531) to that Q&A suggested that the issue lied with a conflicting entry in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. You can either delete the troublesome entries from that file using any text editor or you can use this command to remove entries:

```
$ ssh-keygen -R hostname
```

Where `hostname` would be either the IP address or the name of the server you're attempting to connect from. All the above would be on host **two** by the way.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I *can* ssh to `one` and `two` servers from my workstation without any problems.. the problem starts when I run `scp one:file two:file` from the workstation. And there are is no `known_hosts` file either on **one** or **two**. I just tried to remove keys for **two** (even for **one** to be sure) on my workstation but nothing changed (except for *are you sure y/n* propt).

Comment: @JanSpurny - your referring to your workstation has been a bit confusing in this Q, at least to me. When you say that you mean your laptop/desktop. So you're doing something like this when you say that it "works": `scp workstation:file one:file` and `workstation:file two:file`? Obviously you don't have to say "workstation:file" I'm just saying it explicitly for the conversation's sake.

Comment: Well what I ment is that I ran all commands from my workstation. So it was more like: `workstation$ scp one:file file` and `workstation$ scp file two:file`. Anyway, I think I've solved it. I'll add it as my own answer.

Comment: @JanSpurny - OK, glad you figured it out. Thanks for the question BTW!