# scp from remote to remote does not work if not using -3

Tags: scp, remote, msys

I mean to copy files from one remote server to another.

If using `scp -3`, command succeeds (I have `remote1` and `remote2` in my `~/.ssh/config`)

```
$ scp -p -3 remote1:dir1/file1 remote2:dir2/
```

but when not using `-3`, it fails

```
$ scp -p remote1:dir1/file1 remote2:dir2/
ssh: Could not resolve hostname remote2: Temporary failure in name resolution
lost connection
```

**Why is that?**

As I understand from `man scp` and other sources, `-3` is not mandatory, but simply

```
-3      Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host.  Without this option the data is copied directly between the two remote hosts.
```

I am using msys2, I wouldn't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: is `remote2` configured in `remote1` ?

Comment: @Archemar - No... and it appears that [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163379/137608) is the answer, and this OP is a dupe.
Could you confirm?

Comment: indeed this OP looks like a dupe to me.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio mark it as a duplicate and the poster gets the opportunity to agree, disagree, and we (community) get the opportunity to agree or ignore