# How SCP Hang issue resolve after changing MTU Value?

Tags: networking, ftp, scp

I had an issue with doing SCP between two machines, both machines had MTU value 8950 and in most of the time it hangs after transferring 4740 bytes and File size is 4697 Bytes, Below are some logs from SCP.

```
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
Sending file modes: C0555 4697 system_test_precheck
debug3: Wrote 84 bytes for a total of 1953
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 38
Sink: C0555 4697 system_test_precheck
debug2: channel 0: written 38 to efd 6
system_test_precheck                                                                                                                                                                                       100% 4697     4.6KB/s   00:00    
debug3: Wrote 4740 bytes for a total of 6693
debug3: Wrote 52 bytes for a total of 6745
```

it hangs after that

I did google and found below links where I found solution for that [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14187/why-does-scp-hang-on-copying-files-larger-than-1405-bytes) from below question but i need more details that is not in the answer

Why does SCP hang on copying files larger than 1405 bytes?

I changed MTU from 8950 to 1400 on source machine from where I am doing SCP.

I want to know what was the issue and how did it worked for me?

Comment: The comments attached to the answer on that question address the "how" very nicely.

Comment: @roaima I have found answer from the same link and already mentioned, the reason i posted because i didn't understood it

Comment: That isn't clear in your question. The question you actually asked has already been addressed.