# Some websites load while others load forever in Linux Mint 18

Tags: networking, linux-mint

I have installed Linux Mint 18 64 bit and noticed Google and Youtube and others loading flawlessly (even HD videos play) but some sites like Wikipedia don't show up even though the tabs in Mozilla either show "loading" or show "wikipedia - the free encyclopedia" but then the site doesn't appear.

The computer loads some sites but doesn't load others, and they don't change – if site A doesn't load then it doesn't load next time either. If site B loads then it loads afterwards too.

Last time I checked the internet connection in a different computer – with windows – everything worked, so it's not ISP's fault.

It does this even with ufw disabled.

Doesn't work with Mint liveDVD either. It's the same thing.

If I open up a web proxy and type in Wikipedia then it goes there.  Same thing with other browsers.

After typing `wget wikipedia.org`:

```
--2016-07-20 21:30:40--  http://wikipedia.org/

Resolving wikipedia.org (wikipedia.org)... 91.198.174.192, 2620:0:862:ed1a::1

Connecting to wikipedia.org (wikipedia.org)|91.198.174.192|:80... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 TLS Redirect

Location: https://wikipedia.org/ [following]

--2016-07-20 21:30:40--  https://wikipedia.org/

Connecting to wikipedia.org (wikipedia.org)|91.198.174.192|:443... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently

Location: https://www.wikipedia.org/ [following]

--2016-07-20 21:30:40--  https://www.wikipedia.org/

Resolving www.wikipedia.org (www.wikipedia.org)... 91.198.174.192, 

2620:0:862:ed1a::1


Connecting to www.wikipedia.org (www.wikipedia.org)|91.198.174.192|:443... connected.


HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

Length: unspecified [text/html]

Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html              [<=>                 ]       0 --.-KB/s
```

..and it stops and never continues. I had to interrupt it.

The index.html I found in my home folder is totally empty BUT at the tab it says "Wikipedia".

`dig wikipedia.org` output is:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> wikipedia.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15688
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wikipedia.org.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wikipedia.org.      343 IN  A   91.198.174.192

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 193.231.252.1#53(193.231.252.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 20 21:38:59 EEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58
```

After `ping -c 3 wikipedia.org`:

```
PING wikipedia.org (91.198.174.192) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from text-lb.esams.wikimedia.org (91.198.174.192): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=50.5 ms
64 bytes from text-lb.esams.wikimedia.org (91.198.174.192): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=48.3 ms
64 bytes from text-lb.esams.wikimedia.org (91.198.174.192): icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=49.4 ms

--- wikipedia.org ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 48.342/49.475/50.594/0.954 ms
```

After `ping -c 3 91.198.174.192`:

```
PING 91.198.174.192 (91.198.174.192) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.198.174.192: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=50.6 ms
64 bytes from 91.198.174.192: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=50.7 ms
64 bytes from 91.198.174.192: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=48.2 ms

--- 91.198.174.192 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 48.267/49.898/50.796/1.155 ms
```

It's not an MTU issue.

---

**Edit**: At the suggestion of mrwhale I will post the output of `route -n`, `ip route`, and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` in both the usable distro and the not-so-usable distro. I mentioned that internet works on a web proxy and he asked me to post this.

### On the usable distro

#### route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 ppp0
10.0.0.1 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 0 0 0 ppp0
```

#### ip route

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev ppp0 proto static
10.0.0.1 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src (here it showed my IP address)
```

#### cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

### On the current broken distro (Linux Mint)

#### route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1 0.0.0.0 UG 100 0 0 ppp0
10.0.0.1 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 100 0 0 ppp0
169.254.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 U 1000 0 0 ppp0
```

#### ip route

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev ppp0 proto static metric 100
10.0.0.1 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src (my IP address) metric 100
169.254.0.0/16 dev ppp0 scope link metric 1000
```

#### cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 193.231.252.1
nameserver 213.154.124.1
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Comment: It may not be an ISP problem but the fact that the installation media has the same problem gives me the impression that the issue is linked to that machine, so probably comes from restrictions on the router.  Did you try bypassing the router to see if that worked.

Comment: I may sound like a noob, but isn't it rather from the motherboard? I don't have a modem/router because internet comes directly from a cable. A guy from the ISP came and plugged my internet cable into his PC on which Windows was installed and he experienced no problems. By the way isn't it probable that I screwed something up in pppoe settings or pppoeconf? If yes, how can I repair it?

Comment: Omg.  That last comment does bring a lot of confusion to your setup as **all** providers use some kind of modem which includes an Ethernet port, and cable Internet does not use PPPoE.  Note that a bad PPPoE configuration can not cause only some sites to work.  Please tell us exactly what device is connected to your computer to provide you Internet access as well as the output of `ifconfig` which should help clarify a few things.

Comment: What makes you think this isn't an MTU issue? The symptoms match. Please read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14187/why-does-scp-hang-on-copying-files-larger-than-1405-bytes , http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4261/cant-access-select-https-sites-on-linux-over-pppoe , http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11107/how-to-diagnose-a-reliably-unreliable-connection

Comment: Want to see something beautiful? ping -c 1 -s 1500 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 1500(1528) bytes of data.
1508 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=13.9 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.946/13.946/13.946/0.000 ms ping -c 1 -s 9000 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 9000(9028) bytes of data.
9008 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=15.1 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.158/15.158/15.158/0.000 ms