# What do you explain my issue with if I can send an MTU packet of this size?

Tags: networking, linux-mint

See this: [Some websites load while others load forever in Linux Mint 18](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297776/some-websites-load-while-others-load-forever-in-linux-mint-18)

And this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298119/is-there-anything-suspicious-in-my-ifconfig

Also don't forget about this:

ping -c 1 -s 1500 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 1500(1528) bytes of data.
1508 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=13.9 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.946/13.946/13.946/0.000 ms

ping -c 1 -s 1600 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 1600(1628) bytes of data.
1608 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=14.1 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.128/14.128/14.128/0.000 ms

ping -c 1 -s 9000 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 9000(9028) bytes of data.
9008 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=15.1 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.158/15.158/15.158/0.000 ms

Only thing is, I changed MTU of enpxxx and ppp0 and it's now 1492 in ifconfig.

Comment: this should be an edit or comment ot your previous post

Comment: It appears you're asking why you can successfully ping with a packet bigger than your MTU...

Answer (score 1):

Pinging with a larger packet than the path MTU worked because you didn't give ping options to prevent it from sending IP fragments.

With the `ping` I have installed and my 1500-byte MTU it'd be:

`ping -M do -s 1472 8.8.8.8` works, whereas `ping -M do -s 1473 8.8.8.8` gives an error. The `-M do` option prohibits fragmentation.