# Asking rsync to transfer files without connecting to the remote rsync server?

Tags: ssh, rsync

If I understand correctly, `rsync` tries to connect to a remote `rsync` server when transferring files via `-e ssh`. This worked well for me most of the time, but I am having problems rsyncing with a particular server.

If I verbose the transfer:

```
rsync -ar --verbose --progress source_file -e ssh server:dest_file
```

I see the following:

```
opening connection using: ssh server rsync --server -vvlogDtpre.iLsf .
```

and it stands there, forever. I should note that I can manually ssh into that machine with no problem. In case it matters, I have a `ControlMaster` set up for this connection in my ssh config file, i.e.:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
```

This made me think about two questions:

1. Why can't rsync connect to this particular server?
2. Is there a way to force rsync to act like scp (and skip connecting to the remote rsync server)?

Comment: Does `scp` work? If interactive ssh (mostly) works but scp and rsync don't, read about [MTU problems](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4261).

Comment: @Guilles, I just checked and `scp` doesn't work either. Thanks for the link to the thread on MTU! I'll make sure to update this post as soon as I find out if that's relevant to my case.

Comment: Is rsync installed on the remote server.  Are both the local and remote rsync have a somewhat similar version?  I have seen unusual issues in a few places where there is a large difference in versions.

Comment: Is it possible you are running into os specific problems on the other end such as a full disk/partition/lv or something like that? What kind of server is this (linux/solaris/etc). Can you paste some logs (syslog for example) or the output of df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to try:

- Try using `rsync -e "ssh -vvv"` to get more output.
- Try debugging on the server.
- Do you have any text output when you log in (e.g., running `fortune`, or anything that prints)?
- You said that you can `ssh`. Can you in fact `scp` properly?