# Discover MTU between me and destination IP

Tags: networking, ip, file-transfer

In a case I can use only `UDP` and `ICMP` protocols, how can I discover, in bytes, the [path MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit#Path_MTU_Discovery) for packet transfer from my computer to a destination IP?

Comment: Do you want to solve this programmatically or with ping? Ping and either shell programming or combined with traceroute are options for example. Also do you want ipv4 or ipv6?

Comment: @Max: shell programming it sounds good , have an idea for that ?

Comment: I thought about using `ping -s $SIZE -c 1 -M dont` and lowering that `SIZE` value till it works, or just having a look at the `ICMP` returns via `tcpdump` if we are talking ipv6 but `traceroute` has this built in I just realized.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for, is easiest gotten via `traceroute --mtu <target>`; maybe with a `-6` switch thrown in for good measure depending on your interests.
Linux `traceroute` uses UDP as a default, if you believe your luck is better with ICMP try also `-I`.

Answer (score 25):

A quick search with `apropos mtu` on CentOS5 turned out:

`tracepath` traces path to a network host discovering MTU along this path

This command even works unprivileged in user space.

Comment: I prefer this over `traceroute` since it returns a simple result at the end and I don't have to look for the last hop that returned a different MTU.

Comment: Alas, `tracepath` doesn't let you choose which network interface to use.  You can choose with `traceroute` (using `-i`).

Answer (score 4):

Under Python, you are just one install away:

```
pip install ofunctions.network
```

Then you can run the following python code

```
from ofunctions.network import probe_mtu

print(probe_mtu(target_IP))
```

This is the simplest syntax, but you may also force ICMPv6 or ICMPv4 discovery, and limit the minimum and maximum probe settings in order for the probing to happen faster.

Disclaimer: I am the author of ofunctions ;)

Comment: I guessed that you meant `print(probe_mtu("142.250.187.206"))`, but that just gave me `ValueError: Both sides of the argument list are unexpected results`. Did I misunderstand your instructions?

Comment: I just tried that code again. Works for me. What version of python and ofunctions.network do you use ?

Comment: Python 3.9.9 and ofunctions.network-1.0.0

Comment: I've just tried with Python 3.9.9 x64 on Win10 x64 without any trouble. There may be two solutions, or you don't have internet while trying this command (or at least ECHO request filtering somewhere), or your ping command is not standard. Can you give more details on your environment in order to replicate the issue ?

Comment: Made an improvement of ofunctions.network in order to print an obvious message when ICMP request could not be done. See https://github.com/netinvent/ofunctions/commit/15dcdeb8fbf4f1a49cfbd1581081b378dbe47fd5

Comment: It's pretty slow, but it works. If you want to see some progress, run tcpdump along side and see it binary searching (i believe) the value for the path mtu. Rough command: `sudo tcpdump -i any icmp -n`