# Shell Hangs After Running cd, ls, vim over ssh

Tags: ssh

I'm logging onto a computer cluster over ssh. The problem is I can't do much more than that. 
Whenever I run things, eg: `vim`, `cd`, `ls` the cursor just hangs there and nothing else happens.

- I've heard it could be something to do with MPUs? Not an expert so I don't know.
- I was using a VPN but now I'm connected directly to the network and the problem still happens.

Do you have any idea why this could be?

Edit: thank you commentors for your suggestions. My sysadmin solved the problem for me, so your suggestions will have to remain suggestions as I can't verify them. However, please answer the question for any straggler who finds themselves with this obscure issue in the future.

Comment: Please update the original post of yours with the output from these commands:  `alias` , `echo ${PATH}`, provided you can get a shell prompt.   Sometimes, an erroneous escape sequence on your shell prompt, may turn it into a _nothing_, so even if you see nothing, try running a simple command and see what reaction you will get.

Comment: I've seen this happen when the MTU is set lower on one of the internet connections. I would try setting the MTU to somewhere in the low 1400's on the actual NIC to see if that fixes it. Info on how to adjust MTU [here](http://tinyurl.com/adjust-mtu).

Comment: MPU? Did you mean MTU? That's indeed a possibility, see if your symptoms match: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124946/ssh-session-through-openvpn-cuts-off-locks-up-after-a-few-lines

Comment: Start `ssh` with 1 or more `-v` options.