# SCP Lost Connection

Tags: ssh

I can successfully connect to my server via `ssh` but when trying to run the `scp` command I get a connection time out.

```
$ scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.12.2:id_rsa.pub
ssh: connect to host 192.168.12.2 port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

Yes I do have openssh-client and openssh-server installed on both my machines the client and the server.

My router is also configured to forward ssh port 22 and no I don't have a firewall enabled.

Comment: Do you use any special arguments to ssh to the server? In particular, `-p`?

Comment: No it ssh directly without any arguments, My setup is passwordless with ssh key authentication.

Comment: So, to be clear, if you run `ssh root@192.168.12.2` from the same terminal, immediately before or after the scp attempt, it works?

Comment: Yes I can ssh no problem but scp keeps timing out.

Comment: That's very weird. Because `scp` works by running `ssh`. While its sitting there (before the timeout) you should be able to catch the `ssh` command via `ps x | grep scp` or similar. Does that command work if you run it directly, minus the `scp -t .` at the end?

Comment: When I run `ps x | grep scp` I get `8598 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --colour=auto scp`

Comment: You need to run that while you're running that scp command (between when you hit enter and when it says connection timed out). That presumes you're running ps as the same user; you can use `ps ax` if its as a different user.

Comment: Okay not I got this `8786 pts/1    S+     0:00 scp /home/victorvaldezhidalgo1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.12.2:id_rsa.pub
 8787 pts/1    S+     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -x -oForwardAgent=no -oPermitLocalCommand=no -oClearAllForwardings=yes -l root -- 192.168.12.2 scp -t id_rsa.pub
 8790 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --colour=auto scp`

Comment: scp works on the server side but not on the client side.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment that it works on the server side but not the client side? I thought we were only trying from one side??? Does `ssh` (client) work from the side you're running `scp` on?

Comment: 1. try scp -i with a path to your keys 2. try -v to get more info on the time out

Comment: yes @derobert it works on my side scp doesn't it time out

Comment: does `/usr/bin/ssh -x -oForwardAgent=no -oPermitLocalCommand=no -oClearAllForwardings=yes -l root -- 192.168.12.2` work? That's the command scp is running (without the scp part).

Comment: I go it working again, but with a different authentication key, the previous one had a password for encryption reasons and then well I took it off.

Comment: When you say that SSH works, do you mean an interactive session? If you run a command that produces a lot of output, like `ssh yes | head -n 99999 >99999.out`, does it work? This could be an [MTU problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4261/cant-access-select-https-sites-on-linux-over-pppoe/4319#4319).

Comment: How does the route between the client and the server look like? Post the output of `traceroute -n 192.168.12.2`. This could be a grumpy firewall somewhere in between.

Comment: Is this solved? It is a bit hard to tell from your last comment. I think that derobert's suggestion is a good one. From the `ssh_config` `man` page: `ClearAllForwardings - Specifies that all local, remote, and dynamic port  forwardings  specified in the configuration files or on the command line be cleared. This option is primarily useful when used from the ssh command line to clear port forwardings set in configuration files and is automatically set  by  scp(1) and sftp(1). The argument must be yes or no. The default is no.`

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your command because I don't understand where you are trying to drop the file but if you fix this, it should work:

This is wrong:

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.12.2**:id_rsa.pub**
```

The above line does not have the correct path. It should look like this:

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.12.2:/root(or other user path)/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Basically what you are missing is the ' / ' after the ' : ' and the correct path location to where you want to drop the file. Also as a side-note, you just need the path, the name of the file at the end of that path works more like a renaming feature. So using the above example again, this too is also valid:

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.12.2:/root(or other user path)/.ssh/
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't using the wrong port. To specify a port, pass the -P option. See also https://askubuntu.com/a/182482