# SSH - packet_write_wait broken pipe

Tags: ssh

I just got a dedicated host with Ubuntu installed on it. I am running OS X Sierra on my local machine. I have access to the host via SSH and a Vesta Control Panel. But whenever I try to SSH into the host, I get to the login screen, and after entering the correct password, I get the following error:

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 123.456.789.10 port 22: Broken pipe
```

I tried changing the settings in `/etc/ssh/ssh` to set the timeout to 120 and the keep alive setting to no. I also tried changing the **KeepAlive** setting to *yes*. This did nothing for me.

I tried upgrading from El Capitan to Sierra. On El Capitan, I was getting an ssh_dispatch_run_fatal error when I tried to connect with `ssh` but now on Sierra I get the error in the title of this question.

The only other access to my host is via the Vesta Control Panel. There are several options for SSH. Back on El Capitan, I managed to SSH in once when I changed the mode to screen, but that didn't last long.

My internet connection is fine as I can browse the internet and do other things. It seems to be whenever I successfully login with the root password, I get the broken pipe error.

The only other access I have to the machine is via the Vesta control panel, so I can't try any command line commands ATM.

Output of `ssh -v` :

```
Toms-Mac-mini:~ tommorison$ ssh -v root@185.153.198.212

OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/tommorison/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/tommorison/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 185.153.198.212 [185.153.198.212] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/tommorison/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommorison/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommorison/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommorison/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommorison/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommorison/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommorison/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/tommorison/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 185.153.198.212:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:kWXFuyqgytN7PX9gbgxmUj4HlU0pYesfEmCLeDJTRms
debug1: Host '185.153.198.212' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/tommorison/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/tommorison/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/tommorison/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/tommorison/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/tommorison/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: What output do you get when you try to log into the host with "ssh -v". Are you able to get sshd logs from your connection attempt?

Comment: I added the output in my question.

Comment: Please edit your post and copy-paste the output of `ssh -v`, but this time use the code block tool (Ctrl+K or `{}` button) instead of the quote tool. The quote tool reformats lines and that makes the log unreadable.

Comment: I can think of two reasons why a connection might get dropped after a successful login. One is a weird firewall somewhere; that's difficult to investigate unless you can try different origin and destination locations. Another is an [MTU problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4261/cant-access-select-https-sites-on-linux-over-pppoe) (due to some configuration on the server side, since you generally don't have a problem with Internet connections). Does something get displayed after you log in (e.g. a motd file) or should you just get a shell prompt? Does reducing the MTU help?

Comment: I should just get a shell prompt after logging into the server, I tried changing the MTU to 1000, but that did not do anything. I don't think it's a firewall issue because in Vesta, SSH is allowed in the firewall rules when I check those settings. I will admit I am a bit confused. I am connected to the internet over a WiFi connection and according to `ifconfig -a` en1 is my WiFi connection (since that's the only adapter with a IP address) though I am not sure.

Comment: Weird, it worked all of the sudden... Thanks everyone!

Comment: Did you do anything to fix the problem? Or, to quote xkcd, "What did you see?!"