# ssh hangs for git push

Tags: ssh, git

I have setup a git server on a remote machine. I can connect to it through ssh with no problem and also git pull from it. I can however not git push to it and attempting to do so results in the command hanging forever. Doing the command with ssh set to verbose output I get this:

```
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
[...]
```

More information:

I can git push to a different server without problem (tried gitlab).

Also scp works fine: a 2mb file was done in about a second.

I'm not on a corporate network.

Even more:

I have now tried to check the MTU with `tracepath` and reduced it to 1280 which is well below the 1460 that tracepath reportet, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Does git push work to a different server? If you can arrange it, does it work when you use a different Internet provider? What about SSH sessions that are not git push but upload a large amount of data (e.g. `scp` of a 1MB file from your client to your server)? Some possibilities: an [MTU problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4261) (sometimes it's unidirectional); an [IDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) (if you're on a corporate network); a bandwidth limiter.

Comment: I can git push to a different server (tried gitlab) and also scp works fine. A 2mb file was done in about a second. I'm not on a corporate network. Unfortunately I can't try a different Internet provider currently.